# intellij idea not opening because of jdk/bin/java

Tags: java, jdk, intellij

I am relatively new to ubuntu. i am using idea intellij from jetbrains for developing applications with gwt and java. Recently i have installed ubuntu 14.04 and everything works fine but idea 13. I have jdki586-1.7 and i have installed it using [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux) tutorial. Then i have extracted intellij to my home directory and tried to launch idea.sh from terminal with:

```
./idea.sh
```

from path/to/idea/bin directory. But, it gave me this error:

```
./idea.sh: 1: eval: /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java: not found
```

I have searched through the Internet, but couldn't find similar topic.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same issue but the above answer did not solve my issue. I had to switch as a root user then running idea.sh worked fine without any issue. May be a permission issue or setting $PATH may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you did not setup java correctly. Using the webupd8 ppa is the easiest way to install java on ubuntu. Just type these lines in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

then verify that your java is ready

```
java -version
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have tried this and it asked me to check correctness of the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`. i have reinstalled ca-certificates and it didn't help as well: still incorrect installed jdk and i cannot launch idea intelliJ

Comment: Thanks, I have figured it out. The thing i have to do was to export proxies and then use sudo -E instead of sudo alone before `add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`. it worked with `sudo -E ...`.